# not only A of W but also { B, C, D / X, Y, Z}

Tags: conjunctions, scoping

From [this article](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/03/18/noam-chomsky-on-the-roots-of-american-racism/?_r=0) I found this sentence -

> The achievement includes **not only** *the great wealth of* the planter aristocracy **but also** American and British manufacturing, commerce and the financial institutions of modern state capitalism.

I doubt the placement of **the great wealth of** there. I think it has to have **the great wealth of** before **not only**. Or you have to include **the great wealth of** after **but also**.

The way the original sentence is written it seems like the achievement includes **the great wealth of the planter aristocracy** and **American and British manufacturing, commerce and the financial institutions of modern state capitalism.** (*not the great wealth of American and British manufacturing, commerce and the financial institutions of modern state capitalism.*)

Isn't it unlikely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prof. Chomsky says exactly what he means. He's aware that everybody in his audience knows that slavery made the Southern planter aristocracy wealthy; what he is eager to add is  that slavery was also the foundation on which the other "progressive" institutions were erected:

> The industrial revolution was based on cotton, produced primarily in the slave labor camps of the United States.

He is not arguing that slavery made other people wealthy but that it made other institutions possible.

Comment: +1 for "Prof. Chomsky says exactly what he means". If we have to assume Chomsky starts making language mistakes, there's little left to hold on to :D

Comment: @oerkelens Well, to be fair, Chomsky's been rewriting his theory continuously since 1957, so we gotta assume that he *useta* make mistakes :)